# Having trouble installing Curl on Solaris 10

Tags: unix, curl, installation, solaris

Here is what I am doing, this is purely through PuTTy on my windows system onto a Solaris VM.

```
# ls
curl-7.27.0          curl-7.27.0.tar.bz2  hostName.pl          starthere.desktop
# cd curl-7.27.0
# ls
Android.mk           README               configure.ac         m4
CHANGES              RELEASE-NOTES        curl-config.in       maketgz
CMake                acinclude.m4         curl-style.el        missing
CMakeLists.txt       aclocal.m4           depcomp              mkinstalldirs
COPYING              buildconf            docs                 packages
MacOSX-Framework     compile              include              sample.emacs
Makefile             config.guess         install-sh           src
Makefile.am          config.log           lib                  tests
Makefile.in          config.sub           libcurl.pc.in        vc6curl.dsw
Makefile.msvc.names  configure            ltmain.sh            winbuild
# ./configure
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... no
checking whether to enable debug build options... no
checking whether to enable compiler optimizer... (assumed) yes
checking whether to enable strict compiler warnings... no
checking whether to enable compiler warnings as errors... no
checking whether to enable curl debug memory tracking... no
checking whether to enable hiding of library internal symbols... yes
checking whether to enable c-ares for DNS lookups... no
checking for sed... /usr/bin/sed
checking for grep... /usr/bin/grep
checking for egrep... /usr/bin/egrep
checking for ar... no
configure: error: ar not found in PATH. Cannot continue without ar.
#
```

It is located on my desktop. Any suggestions? I googled and nothing came up =/
Let me know if this belongs somewhere else...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ar is the GNU archiver

You will need to make sure binutils, which supplies ar, is available on your system.

I'm not familiar with Solaris, but it seems like installing the 'binutils' package should help you out: http://www.opencsw.org/packages/binutils/ .

Answer (score 4):

For Solaris 10, ar is contained in SUNWbtool package.
For Solaris 11, ar is contained in system/linker package.

Comment: On Solaris 10, you'll also need to add /usr/ccs/bin to your $PATH for the SUNWbtools version.  Solaris 11 moved it to /usr/bin so it's in the default $PATH.